# Android API changes affect code somehow

Tags: android, handler, runnable, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have been searching for the cause of my problem on the online documentation, but i cannot seem to locate it.

My code woks fine on API 19, but doesn't seem to work properly on API 22.

Here is the code -

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        if(!killMe) {
            if (countCycles != 5) {
                if (++countPress == 2 ) {
                    takeTwoBreaths();
                } else {
                    mActivity.playMetronomeTick();
                    mStartMetronomeHandler.postDelayed(this, mActivity.getMetronomeTimeUntilFinish());
                }
            } else { //we have finished 5 cycles
                countCPRs++;
                this.stop();
                mActivity.playFinishCPR();
                mActivity.checkPulse(countCPRs);
                newLog("Check pulse");
            }
        }
    }

    private void takeTwoBreaths() {
        countCycles++;
        countPress = 0; // reset counter
        mActivity.playTakeTwoBreaths();
        mStartMetronomeHandler.postDelayed(this,6000); //start again in 6s
    }
```

How it works ( and should work ) on API 19 - Firstly this `Runnable` is started,
then it does `playMetronomeTick()` after which it posts itself to the handler to be called back in 18s. When done, `takeTwoBreaths()` is called which then calls `playTakeTwoBreaths()` and posts itself to be called in 6s. That cycle repeats 5 times.

What it does on API 22 - First cycle goes as planned ( sometimes ) and then when second cycle comes, `takeTwoBreaths()` calls `playTakeTwoBreaths()` sets itself to be called in 6s, and then after those 6s pass, `run()` is called 2x.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on here?

Is my estimation correct, that this is maybe an API issue, or did i screw something up in the code?

Comment: Anything in the Logcat look interesting?

Comment: Nothing in particular, maybe just this - Suspending all threads took: 19.197ms - And some skipped frames... Nothing else...

Comment: look for blue colored logcat lines. you will crack it.

Comment: That 'Suspending all threads' line is a red herring - it's quite common. If you're still stuck - I suggest putting some logging lines into your code - it'll be difficult to narrow something down without more specific info I think.

Comment: Actually, i fixed it by deleting the whole code and re-writing it again. Still not sure why it wasn't working...